# xPath, DOM & NodeList

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I have following HTML which I am trying to read from the DOMNodeList when I query a HTML document with xPath in PHP code. This is my query `$description = $xpath->query("//div[@class='qsc-html-content']");`

I expect that I shall be able to fetch every thing inside 2nd div. Im new to xPath in PHP. The problem is when I try anything like following :

```
        if(isset($description) && is_object($description)){
        echo "DESCIPTION SET";
        echo $description->tagName;

        //echo $description->getElementsByTagName("p");
        $productInfo['description'] = trim($description->nodeValue);            
    }
```

I do not get any result.

```
<div class="product-description ">
<div class="qsc-html-content">
    <p><span class="Apple-style-span" style="background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">Farida is a new and upcoming brand in the hookah market which specializes in solid brass hookahs. The designs are very unique and have not been seen in the hookah industry before. </span>This hookah stand about&nbsp;36".</p>
    <ul>
    <li>Farida&nbsp;hose</li>
    <li>Tongs, Grommets, Bowl, &amp; Farida Gold Tray</li>
    </ul>
    <p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-small;">Please Not: </span></strong></span></p>
    <p>&nbsp;Glass bases are mouth blown and sometimes have air bubbles as evidence of this fact. <span style="font-size: xx-small;">Artisans hand paint each glass base, making every one as unique as the artist. This results in a 100% unique finished product that may not look identical to the photo. It also means that sometimes the paint may have a slight smudge, a line may not be perfectly straight, or you may see the artist's brush strokes.</span></p>
    <p>Egyptian products are handmade in a traditional manner. Because these hookahs are handmade, there are usually slight variations from hookah to hookah. Most hookahs contain visible weld lines or unpolished metal at the welds.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color: #ff0000;">FREE STARTER KIT INCLUDES:</span> 1 Holland Charcoal, 10 Mouth Tips, and 2 AL Fakher 50g Tobbacos Select Flavors</p>
    <p><img alt="" height="55" src="media/round tablets.jpg" width="103" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="" height="81" src="media/male_mouth_tips.jpg" width="109" /> <img alt="" height="86" src="media/d_al_fakher_50g.jpg" width="126" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Some one can please guide me where I am wrong. There is another problem where I am trying to fetch list of anchor tags by xPath query and the result is returning only singe anchor.

I had banged my head onto this for last 2 hours. I am exhausted now.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from `$xpath->query(...)` is a DOMNodeList object. It's not a single element, so using:

```
echo $description->tagName;
```

is wrong. Instead you should iterate the result, like this:

```
$description = $xpath->query("//div[@class='qsc-html-content']");
foreach ($description as $item) {
    echo $item->tagName . "\n";
}
```

Comment: foreach loop didn't output anything. when i check $description->length it shows "0"

Comment: OK i just tried the exact HTML code you sent and it works as expected. The code `foreach ($description as $item) echo $item->tagName;` returns "div". So your problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Im using tidy class to well format the HTML read from HTML Page on server. Do you think that could be a reason?

Comment: Yess. when i bypass tidy and directly load the HTML file into DomDocument it worked.